# Two APL functions give different results, but their boxing is identical

Tags: function, apl, dyalog

I am trying to create an APL function which returns differences (non-identical items with identical index) between two vectors.
I have come up with the following and it works fine, subtracting two vectors and discarding zeroes from the result:

```
func ← {((⍺-⍵)≠0)/(⍺-⍵)}
```

However, I was not satisfied with repeating the `(⍺-⍵)` part, so I optimized it a little:

```
func ← {(⍺ (0≠-) ⍵) / (⍺-⍵)}
```

That also works (`(1 2 3 4) func (4 2 0 4)` returns `-3 3`, as expected), so I went ahead:

```
func ← {⍺ ((0≠-)/-) ⍵}
```

And that, in fact, does not work for vectors longer than one element. It just returns `1` whenever there is a difference, without showing how big it is (`(1 2 3 4) func (4 2 0 4)` now returns `1`). Why?

I checked the problematic function both in https://tryapl.org editor and in a local environment - neither works.
I checked the composition rules again - I tried to use the one saying that `⍺ (f g h) ⍵`
and  `(⍺ f ⍵) g (⍺ h ⍵)` are equivalent, where in my case:

- `f` is the `(0≠-)` train,
- `g` is the compression function `/`,
- `h` is the subtraction funcion `-`.

Perhaps the most peculiar thing for me - I checked the boxing of two functions. It's identical!

```
⍝ the working function
⍝ func ← {(⍺ (0≠-) ⍵) / (⍺-⍵)}

    ]boxing on
    ((0≠-))/(-)
┌───────────┬─┐
│┌───────┬─┐│-│
││┌─┬─┬─┐│/││ │
│││0│≠│-││ ││ │
││└─┴─┴─┘│ ││ │
│└───────┴─┘│ │
└───────────┴─┘
```

```
⍝ the "broken" function
⍝ func ← {⍺ ((0≠-)/-) ⍵}

    ]boxing on
    ((0≠-)/-)
┌───────────┬─┐
│┌───────┬─┐│-│
││┌─┬─┬─┐│/││ │
│││0│≠│-││ ││ │
││└─┴─┴─┘│ ││ │
│└───────┴─┘│ │
└───────────┴─┘
```

It's also identical in tree mode and parentheses mode.

What happened? Am I not allowed to nest trains? Did I get my composition parameters wrong? Did I make a typo while checking the boxings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that `/` wants to be an operator in a train. You have to coerce it into its function form:

```
  1 2 3 4 ((0≠-)⊢⍤/-) 4 2 0 4
┌→───┐
│¯3 3│
└~───┘
```

The `⊢⍤/` might be weird-looking, but it's the "slash-as-function" pattern to commit to memory when using trains.

Note the difference:

```
  (0≠-)/-
    ┌┴┐
    / -
  ┌─┘
┌─┼─┐
0 ≠ -

  (0≠-)⊢⍤/-
  ┌────┼─┐
┌─┼─┐  ⍤ -
0 ≠ - ┌┴┐
      ⊢ /
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked like a charm! This structure asks the `/` to take its argument from outside the train rather than grab the thing closest to it (in this case another function), am I thinking correctly?

Comment: @kamilok04 Well, `⍤/` forces `/` to be a function, since a dyadic operator like `⍤` cannot be to the immediate left of another operator. Everything else follows.